# How can I get context from a view?

Tags: android, android-context

I have implemented a [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) to override the `onReceivedError()` event. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
    InternetConnectivityChecker internetConnectivityChecker = new InternetConnectivityChecker(view.getContext().getApplicationContext());

    onReceivedErrorListener.onReceivedError();
    if (internetConnectivityChecker.isConnected() == false) {

    }
}
```

And, here is my `InternetConnectivityChecker` class:

```
package com.sama7.sama;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class InternetConnectivityChecker {
    private Context context;

    public InternetConnectivityChecker(Context context) {
        context = context;
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        NetworkInfo info = ((ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (info == null || !info.isConnected()) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

When running this code, I'm getting an exception, saying:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                at com.sama7.sama.InternetConnectivityChecker.isConnected(InternetConnectivityChecker.java:15)
```

Why is my context a null object? And, how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Pass context in your `isConnected(Context context)` mthod and then use that that method. it will work.

Comment: please check your Context object is null or not first and also put this.context = context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace:

```
context = context;
```

with:

```
this.context = context;
```

so that you set the value of your field. As it stands, you are setting a method parameter to itself.

Comment: I made the change. I'm still getting the same error – maybe the `view.getContext().getApplicationContext()` is returning null?

Comment: @ParhamDoustdar: I doubt that. Set a breakpoint or use Log statements to determine where the `null` is getting introduced.

Answer (score 1):

to get context of application you can use [getApplicationContext](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()) . this will give you the context of the application you are working on.

thank you

Comment: try using only getApplicationContext() instead of view.getContext().getApplicationContext() . and if the reference problem occur then use view.getApplicationContext().

Comment: The `WebView` class doesn't have `getApplicationContext`. My class, `SamaWebViewClient`, extends `WebViewClient`, which doesn't have `getApplicationContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

The view has a method to get the context. See the android API for [getContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29).

Comment: I thought I am using that in my `onReceivedError()` callback. Am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: Problem is that the line in your code that uses `getContext()` is so long that it can't be seen without scrolling over, and it can take a while to figure that out. :)